# "The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file" while using docker-dotnet-sonarscanner

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to check the code coverage locally using using [docker-dotnet-sonarscanner](https://github.com/burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner) on Windows.

My steps until now:

1. Run the container with the Sonarqube, like so, and it's working, I checked:

   `docker run -d --name sonarqube -p 9000:9000 -p 9092:9092 sonarqube`
2. Now, I'm trying to execute the analyze, inside my project folder, I ran:

   `docker run --name dotnet-scanner -it --rm -v $(pwd) \
   -e PROJECT_KEY=ConsoleApplication1 \
   -e PROJECT_NAME=ConsoleApplication1 \
   -e PROJECT_VERSION=1.0 \
   -e HOST=my_ip_address:9000 \
   -e LOGIN_KEY=the_key_I_got_on_local_Server\
   burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner`

Specifically saying, that:

```
winpty docker run --name dotnet-scanner -it --rm -v $(pwd) -e PROJECT_KEY=rede-merchants-cancel-api -e PROJECT_NAME=rede-merchants-cancel-api -e PROJECT_VERSION=2.0 -e HOST=http://172.18.2.230:9000 -e LOGIN_KEY=d9941989468a4fd81e3ffc4abbef466a98ddfb19 burakince/docker-dotnet-sonarscanner
```

But I get the following output:

> dotnet restore
>   MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a p
>   roject or solution file.
>    dotnet build
>   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Core
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a p
>   roject or solution file.
>    dotnet test
>   MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a p
>   roject or solution file.
>    mono /opt/sonar-scanner-msbuild/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login=d9941989468a4fd81e3ffc4abbef466a9
>   8ddfb19

But I checked, and it has the `.sln`, it's on the solution folder.